# What is the formula for calculating the months till pay off of a credit card that includes the APR?

Tags: credit-card, calculation, repayment, apr, spreadsheet

I'm playing around in Excel attempting to get **the total months to pay off** a credit card. I'm not looking to pay off *by* a certain date. I just want to know how long it will take me to pay off what I currently own. Adjusting the monthly payment from minimum amount due, to adding a few extra hundred dollars to watch the months come down.

I have the *APR*, *Monthly Min Due %*, and the *Balance*, and I know I can just take the total balance and divide that by my monthly amount and that will give me the total months, if I had 0 interest and no more charges.

But what I am looking for is **how to include the APR into the calculation**. What is the formula where I don't have to make a giant spread sheet with multiple rows showing each months principle balance and pay off etc..? I just want to be able to plug in my monthly amount I want to pay, and watch the months go up or down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use the [`NPER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nper-function-240535b5-6653-4d2d-bfcf-b6a38151d815) function to calculate the number of periods until payoff given a constant payment amount:

```
Balance   1,000
Rate      5%
Payment   100
NPER      10.23557252    =NPER(5%/12,100,-1000)
```

Note that if you divide the APR by 12 to get a monthly rate, NPER will give you the number of *months* until payoff.